# Issues with concating two dataframe. Both have the same number of rows but they dont merge perfectly

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes

title_w2v (This was extracted from df_fe to do some feature engineering on it)
449 rows × 1 columns
index 0-448

df_fe
449 rows × 18 columns
index 0-452

I am trying to concat them together as below but the results return back
453 rows × 19 columns

```
df_result = pd.concat([df_fe, title_w2v], axis=1, join='inner')
```

which is not what I am after. I would like df_result to be 449 rows × 19 columns

I think the issue might be to do with the fact that df_fe has some index positions missing (I removed some rows). Is there a way to reset the index

Comment: Doesn't `df_result = pd.concat([df_fe.reset_index(), title_w2v.reset_index()], axis=1, join='inner')` work?

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I am a bit confused by the inner and outer join. Both return the same result now. I guess thats because we now have the same index reset?

Comment: That's because the two dataframes have the same index. Inner returns only the indices that match, outer returns the union of both (with NaNs filling up the empty spaces when the indices don't match). Since now all indices match, the two operations are essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add axis

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```